# swift AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification not work

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayeritem

I create a class named DecryptAudioPlayer,it inherit NSObject,this class refrenced a AVPlayer,and observe the notice AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification when init.like below:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playToEnd(_:)), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)
}
```

and i have the method:

```
func playToEnd(notification:NSNotification) {
    Log.printLog("notification:\(notification)")
}
```

but sometimes the player's ower can't recived the AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,i am very confused.it seems the AVPlayerItem may don't post AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification when its end time ,who can tell me why?

Comment: Are you adding the observer after you init the player.

Comment: of course.the player is owed by DecryptAudioPlayer,i add the observe to the owe.

Comment: In the notification object add the currentItem of the player

Comment: i just want to recived AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification whatever the notice come from any avplayeritem,so i add the observe when init and the object is nil.the suitation is,there are many avplayeritems to be play seriral,i can recived most of all,but a few i can't recived, this is the problem i have to solve.

Comment: I guess it may be the local audio files has some problem to cause that. But when the suitation happened, I can get the stalled notification to solve the problem. So, my question could be put down for a while. Thanks for you mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get the stalled notification to solve the problem. So the question could be put down for a while.